# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' while using kinit.stdin.write('%s\n' % password)

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to connect to SQL server from Linux machine using python. However facing an issue while trying to get the kerbos ticket. Below is the code i am using.

```
# Login Credentials
userid = "username"
password = "password"
realm="realm.com"
kinit = '/usr/bin/kinit'

# Get Fresh Kerberos Ticket
kinit_args = [ kinit, '%s@%s' % (userid, realm) ]
kinit = Popen(kinit_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
kinit.stdin.write('%s\n' % password)
kinit.wait()

Error message displayed :
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "poc_test1.py", line 25, in <module>
      kinit.stdin.write('%s\n' % password)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You need to encode() the `write`-string as bytes so python knows how to send the correct bytes over the pipe.

Change the line like to look like this:

```py
kinit.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(password).encode('utf-8'))
```

The `"".format()` is a newer version of the old format string syntax. Afterwards its encoded to bytes assuming UTF-8 encoding for the password string, which should be default.

But I would also suggest replacing the `stdin.write` and `wait` with the newer communicate which should look like this:

```py
kinit = Popen(kinit_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
kinit.communicate(input="{}\n".format(password).encode("utf-8"))
```